# Calculating Percentage (%) of Total SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use a query to perform the following operation:

- Takes all records entered by a user on a certain date `(SELECT count(*) from table WHERE user = "root" and date(dt) = NOW())`
- Get all records entered by the user on a certain date when any field is empty `( (SELECT count(*) from table WHERE user = "root" and field1 = "" and date(dt) = NOW()))`
- Return the percentage of records that contain empty fields

SQL Table

```
 -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Tempo de geração: 16-Abr-2021 às 23:17
-- Versão do servidor: 5.7.31
-- versão do PHP: 7.3.21

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Banco de dados: `db_test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tbl`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `field1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tbl`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl` (`user`, `field1`, `dt`) VALUES
('root', 'not empty', '2021-04-17 00:17:27'),
('root', '', '2021-04-17 00:17:27');
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Example table

```
+------+-----------+
| user |  field1   |
+------+-----------+
| root | not empty |
| root |           |
+------+-----------+
```

Expected output

```
+------+-------------------------------------+
| user | perc_register_that_have_empty_field |
+------+-------------------------------------+
| root |                                  50 |
+------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Don't get used to double quote string literals. In standard SQL and many DBMS these are for identifiers. For string literals single quotes are used. Also using single quotes for string literals in MySQL will make it easier to port the code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count an expression. For example:

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when field1 = '' or field1 is null then 1 else 0 end) /
  count(*) as perc_register_that_have_empty_field
from t 
WHERE user = 'root' and date(dt) = curdate()
```

Result:

```
 perc_register_that_have_empty_field 
 ----------------------------------- 
 0.4000
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dXqyF3E3SEWruEozphzZm/2).